# How can an Android smartphone pretend to be a tablet? (App UI like tablets)

Tags: samsung, tablet, sony-xperia, youtube, screen-resolution

Smartphones have heavy restrictions, compared to tablets.
[image: Already an annoying flaw in 2012 (Galaxy S3, Note 2), not yet fixed on Galaxy Note 8. **Sony Xperia** has fixed it with Z2, however.]

- Many applications, **even homescreen and lockscreen,** enforce vertical rotation. http://www.quora.com/Its-2016-Why-wont-my-homescreen-and-my-lockscreen-rotate
- YouTube mobile: Comments and related videos can not be browsed in horizontal view on the right display size like this on tablets:
  [image: YouTube horizontal view on tablets.]
- If I use my phone via MHL-HDMi or Miracast/Screen Mirroring on an external display, **vertical rotation enforcement is highly annoying.**
- Some applications can override rotation enforcement, but **the running application still thinks it is running on a smartphone, and keeps DPi low.**

How can I make an application such as YouTube think that the device appears as tablet, so that it can show a superior user interface, instead of the crippled mobile UI which nobody can stand?.

Comment: I'm also looking to transform my device into a tablet, see [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/185113/force-tablet-ui-on-a-non-tablet-device). Unfortunately the only viable solution for UI change seems to be Xposed + App Settings, which requires root / custom recovery, and doesn't seem to apply to SystemUI anymore, so my target can't be established, but it might work for you.